# How to r/w between Google Spreadsheet and Firebase Storage?

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, google-sheets, firebase-storage

I have a Google spreadsheet with a list of image filenames in rows (e.g. `tree01`, `tree02`, `car01`, `building01`, etc.) and I have a Firebase Storage with a list of image files with the same name (e.g. `tree01`, `tree02`, `car01`, `building01`, etc.).

How can I get the filename in spreadsheet? Then use the filename to get a download URL in Firebase storage and then put the download URL back to the spreadsheet?

I know how to use Google App Script to r/w with spreadsheet. I have searched online that using Google Web App, using "Web Server for Chrome" and get the download URL from Firebase Storage, but I don't know how to put them together. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve my problem after studying some links. And following up with a useful links for my case.

passing data between google app script (.gs) and google web app (.html)
(https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)

firebase storage tutorial for web app
(https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js)

firebase database tutorial for google app script
(https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase)

I can now communicate between firebase-storage, firebase-database and google spreadsheet

Comment: can you post the code which helped you to communicate between them.